# Push content to fliter.js (jQuery filtering script)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to push new data into a jQuery function called filter.js (https://github.com/jiren/filter.js)

Problem is that I can't figure out how the array for addData should look like.

Here's a demo for the script:
http://jiren.github.io/filter.js/stream.html

Here's the JSON it's fetching from start:
/examples/data/top_movies_data.json

The only documentation about this functions says:

> Add more data to existing filter
>
> If you are streaming json data using ajax then you can add data like
>   this
>
> fJS.addData(data)
>
> Here fJS is Filter.js object and data is json records.

I'm trying to make a new box with this code, it echo's "add", but no box gets added and it's not printing "added"

```
<button id="add">ADD</button>
<script>
$("#add").click(function() {
    alert("add");
    var myNewBox = '[{"name":"Woho","outline":"Two imprisoned men bond over a number of years, finding solace and eventual redemption through acts of common decency.","rating":"9.3","director":"Frank Darabont","year":"1994","stars":["Tim Robbins","Morgan Freeman","Bob Gunton"],"runtime":"142","genre":["Crime","Drama"],"certificate":"R"}]';
    fJS.addData(myNewBox);
    alert("added");
});
</script>
```

The console gives me this error: ReferenceError: fJS is not defined

I would be glad if someone could help me how I should change my function to be able to add data.

Big thanks in advance!

Comment: i don't see where did you defined `fJS`?

Comment: I believe it's defined in the filter.js in the /example/ folder: https://github.com/jiren/filter.js/blob/master/examples/filterjs.js

Comment: no, it's the function. but you have to assign it to a variable or element. the documentation is quite poor tho... it's defined there as `var fJS = filterInit('mustache');`

Comment: Alright, got it now. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Possible conflict:**
When usinf 3rd party plugins somehow `$` is not at its native jQuery state. So to make sure I use it as in its native jQuery, It has to be passed to the function, like so...

```
jQuery(function ($) {...});
```

Doing that you are telling jQuery to instantiate and reassign within that functions.

Then the next step would be to put your code inside...

```
jQuery(function ($) {   
   $("#add").click(function() {
        alert("add");
        var myNewBox = '[{"name......]';
        fJS.addData(myNewBox);
        alert("added");
    });
});
```

Also I would suggest you switch where you have `myNewBox` put `addData` and where you have `addData` put `myNewBox`, this makes more sense because you want you push TO be `addData`, like so...

```
var addData= '[{"name......]';
    fJS.addData(myNewBox);
```